# How to get checked radio button value with angularjs click funciton?

Tags: angularjs

Here are the code:

I want to get checked radio button value with angularjs click funciton?

```
<input type="radio" name="calender" value="calender">
<input type="radio" name="calender" value="calender2" checked="checked">
<button ng-click="get_val($event)">Click</button>

$scope.get_val= function(event)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You need to bind the checkbox value to the controller

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Okay fine, thank for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out this below code snippet on how to bind values to the `ng-model`  and you can access them anywhere in scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl',
  function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.radioVal = 'calender2';
    $scope.get_val = function(event) {
      console.log($scope.radioVal);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="radio" name="calender" value="calender" ng-model="radioVal">
  <input type="radio" name="calender" value="calender2" ng-model="radioVal">
  <button ng-click="get_val($event)">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @AjayMalhotra I would advise you to use this approach, don't use Jquery to get things done some times they can be out of angular context and scope values will not be reflected if change anything in it

Comment: This is my coding blog http://www.ccode4u.com/, you can also add your code and I will post with your name.

Thank you..

Comment: Sure ! I ll check out :) If the answer helped you can you accept it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127611/discussion-between-ajay-malhotra-and-angular-10).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add this to get value

```
var flag_item_val = $("input:radio[name=calender]:checked").val();
```